# Extract month from number of days in a year

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to extract month from number of day in year in Oracle SQL, for instance day 32 is february.

I do not have permission to use procedure, so I have to do it just using select.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get to the solution as follows. First convert the day X into a date and extract the month from it again.
Replace the value 150 with the day of the year you are looking for.

For Month as Number:

```
select extract(month from (to_date(150,'DDD'))) from dual;
```

Works also with the year. Format of the to-date must be simply changed to match.

```
select extract(month from (to_date('150 2022','DDD YYYY'))) from dual;
```

For Month as Month Name:

```
select to_char(to_date(150,'DDD'),'Month') from dual;
```

```
select to_char(to_date('150 2022','DDD YYYY'),'Month') from dual;
```

Comment: Thanks is it working for all years or just 2022?

Comment: Yes, works with all years if you specify the year as well. See example.

Comment: The extra brackets around the `TO_DATE` function are redundant (but not invalid syntax).

Comment: I somehow overlooked the extra brackets. I have corrected.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on a year; not all of them are equal (hint: leap years).

Here's the principle (based on year 2022); adjust it, if needed.

```
SQL> with test (datum) as
  2    (select date '2022-01-01' + level - 1
  3     from dual
  4     connect by level <= date '2023-01-01' - date '2022-01-01'
  5    )
  6  select to_char(datum, 'Mon') result
  7  from test
  8  where datum = date '2022-01-01' + &par_day;
Enter value for par_day: 32

RES
---
Feb

SQL> /
Enter value for par_day: 70

RES
---
Mar

SQL> /
Enter value for par_day: 352

RES
---
Dec

SQL>
```

Comment: Littlefoot your thoughts on wrapping this up in a function?

Comment: @Pugzly: function would have 2 parameters: year (so that CTE would know how to create a calendar for that year) and day. The rest is easy, more or less copy/paste of code I posted.

Comment: wouldn't just need 12/31/YYYY + num_days INTERVAL and RETURN month?

Comment: Try it and see; personally, I upvoted Florian's answer as I find it useful and simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

The day depends on the year, but if you want the current year, something like this should do:

```
select trunc(sysdate,'yy')+32 from dual;
```

(replace 32 with whatever number of days you have MINUS 1)

Comment: Is there any way to have it for any year?

Comment: This is wrong as it is one day out. For example, the 31st day of the year but `SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YY')+31 FROM DUAL;` outputs `01-Feb-2022`. To fix it you need to subtract 1.

Comment: Good catch MT0! Edited the answer to add the comment. And if you want to have it for any year, use what is proposed in the second solution .